# FullCalendar-rails displaying events a day early

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm using Ruby on Rails, fullcalendar-rails and momentjs-rails.

I'm initializing FullCalendar with a single event for demonstration purposes, as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cdb7f02884d2abf6fe40).  The start date is specified as 2015-02-01.  When viewing the month view for January, the event appears on 2015-01-31.  When viewing the month view for February, it appears on 2015-02-01 as well.  If I specify a date that isn't the first of a month, it only appears on the previous day.

I tried making a jsfiddle to demonstrate what's happening, but using the exact same code, the event appeared on the correct date.

I'm completely at my wits end with this one.  I suspect that this is something to do with timezones, but I've tried manually specifying timezones, specifying UTC, telling FullCalendar to ignore timezones entirely, but nothing has helped.  I'm not sure at this point if it's a problem with my Rails server (I don't think so, because the server knows the correct date, time and timezone), the fullcalendar-rails or momentjs-rails gems (doubtful, because I haven't been able to find anybody else having the same issue), my computer (doubtful, because the same code works fine in a jsfiddle), or something else I haven't even considered.  Any help or advice to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The hard coded event changes to a different day? That's really weird. Troubleshoot by removing things and seeing what is causing the problem. Get rid of all the other FC options, the external button controls, etc.

Comment: Also try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736221/full-calendar-places-all-events-to-early . And try setting a time for the hardcoded event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue because i'm using rails 4, what I just use this '2.1.1.0 ' version instead.

Comment: Huh, how bizarre.  I'm using Rails 4 as well.  I had entirely given up on using FullCalendar, but I went back and tried older versions, and sure enough it works!  I'm using 2.2.3 with no issues now.